# Will huge table entries slow down query performance?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table `persons` that looks like this:

`|id | name | age |
|---|------|-----|
|1  |foo   |21   |
|2  |bar   |22   |
|3  |baz   |23   |`

and add a new column `history` where I store a big JSON blob of, let's say ~4MB.

`|id | name | age | history  |
|---|------|-----|----------|
|1  |foo   |21   |JSON ~ 4MB|
|2  |bar   |22   |JSON ~ 4MB|
|3  |baz   |23   |JSON ~ 4MB|`

Will this negatively impact queries against this table overall?

What about queries like:

- `SELECT name FROM persons WHERE ...` (Guess: This won't impact performance)
- `SELECT * FROM persons WHERE ...` (Guess: This will impact performance as the database needs to read and send the big history entry)

Are there any other side effects like various growing caches etc. that could slow down database performance overall?

Comment: I think there will be no negative impact other than the one you mentioned (amount of data transferred in read). There will be an issue when such fields are indexed. Ofcourse you cannot index a 4mb blob :) Otherwise Ok.

Comment: Consider using a separate table and joining on ID. Also look at JSONB and JSON types there could be benefits of using one over the other.

Comment: Interesting blog post in this context: [Postgres large JSON value query performance](https://www.evanjones.ca/postgres-large-json-performance.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON attribute will not be stored in the table itself, but in the *[TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) table* that belongs to the table, which is where all variable-length entries above a certain size are stored (and compressed).

Queries that do not read the JSON values won't affect performance at all, since the TOAST entries won't even be touched. Only if you read the JSON value performance will be affected, mostly because of the additional data read from storage and transmitted to the client, but of course the additional data will also reside in the database cache and compete with other data there.

So your guess is right.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how many transactions and the type of transactions (Create, Read, Update, Delete) that are using this table there could be performance issues.

if you are updating the history lots, you will be doing a lot of updates transactions which will cause the table to reindex each update transaction.

let say table persons is called every time a user logs in and it also updates the history for that user. you are doing a select and update, if this is happening a lot it will cause lots of reindexing and could cause issues when users are logging on and other users are also updating history.

> a better option would be to have a separate table for personupdates with
>   a relation to the person table.

Comment: This ignores PostgreSQL TOAST structures.

Comment: That second paragraph is really difficult to read ... consider what "if you are updating the history lots you will be doing a lot of updates ..." really means?